# Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'Discriminator' in table 'AspNetUserTokens' is specified more than once

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am developing an ASP.NET Core 5 application and I just made a modification to one of the model classes as follows

```
  ...
  public long OfferId { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("OfferId")]
  public RequestOffer Offer { get; set; }
  ...
```

This requires that I add migration and update database.
However, when I try to run **update-database** I get the following error

> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'Discriminator' in table 'AspNetUserTokens' is specified more than once
> I have tried to run the migration with the `-ignoreChanges` flag as I saw in a solution proposed on a similar StackOverflow question but it did not make a difference.

My worry is that I never made any changes to that table (AspNetUserTokens) in this update. However, I realize that in the migration file, I see that all the codes for the previous migrations are repeated as if I am rerunning the migrations afresh which I am not doing.
So, it looks like all the database tables are being recreated. I was expecting the migration file to contain code for only the changes I just made but it rather contains all the changes in the previous migrations as well starting from the very first migration I ran.

I will appreciate any guide to help me resolve this so I can update my database and continue with the project.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, do you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: @AlirezaEsrari, Not yet as you can see. I had to roll back my migrations back and recreate a new fresh migration

Comment: yeah, I did it too. thanks for responding.